# Mustache: How do I create custom helper functions in java

Tags: java, spring-mvc, mustache

I am using `Mustache Template Engine in Java` with `Spring mvc 3`+`Maven`, Templates are rendering properly, but now I want some custom functions for my website. suppose I have 300 characters and now I want to show only 50 characters so need to `truncate` the text and after truncation content ends with `...`. So for this I have to create some custom function. So I am very confused, how and where I need to create custom helper function. Can I create these type of function on my HTML page inside  tag, or I have to create function over java class file. Please give me some suggestion for this. 
HTML Template :

```
<ul>
{{#items}}
    <li>{{name}} : {{detail}}</li>
{{/items}}
<ul>
```

Javascript truncate function

```
 function truncate(str) {
      console.log(str);
      if (str.length > 40) {
          return str.slice(0, 40) + "...";
      } else {
          return str;
      }
  }
```

Comment: IT is advisable to create such type of helper functions in some utility class in java for re-usability.

Comment: then how could I use those helper functions in my HTML pages.?

Comment: IF you have pure HTML pages, define function in javascript.

Comment: ok then how the function will call. I am using this way `<ul>{{#items}}<li>{{name}} : {{detail}}</li><ul>`, and I want to truncate `detail`, can you please tell me how do I call the function over `detail`

Comment: You can truncate the data before you pass it to the html page. Can you explain how you are getting this item list.

Comment: Yes, I am using `MustacheViewResolver` and passing using `mav.addObject(items)` function from controller, and I don't want to pass the truncate detail from controller, I want to handle this from client side only.

Comment: In https://github.com/janl/mustache.js check the section for "Functions" there you can define a function.

Comment: but I am using mustache with java, so how can I add that type of functions or how to pass these functions from java controller.?

Comment: Well as per the example, the function is defined in the data passed from the java controller. Past your view data and let us see.

Comment: ok... but I don't know how to pass a functions from controller

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50113/discussion-between-ray-and-user2518430)

Answer (score 6):

Personally, I do something like...

```
 private static class Scope {
        public String name;

        public Function<String, String> capitalize() {  // the magic is here
            return return (obj) -> ("_" + obj + "_").toUpperCase();
        }
}

public String renderTemplate() {
        MustacheFactory mf = new DefaultMustacheFactory();
        Mustache mustache = mf.compile("template.mustache");
        StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        Scope scope = new Scope();
        scope.names = "boris";
        mustache.execute(stringWriter, scope);
        return stringWriter.toString();
    }
```

with the template..

```
{{#capitalize}} {{ name }} {{/capitalize}}
```